# I want to show a container at bottom of each page in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I want that a container with height 20 should be visible in every screen of my app.
I will have a variable which will tell me whether to display it or not. If it should be displayed, all contents of page will shift up by 20, and if not, everything will work normally. I don't want to overlap it with screen contents like using bottomsheet or stack.

Here is my build function of `MyApp`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    firstCheck=-1;
    ScreenSize.init(context);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MainProvider())],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: myCustomTheme,
        scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: MyRoute.splashScreen,
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Scaffold(
            bottomSheet: ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: showInternetWarning,
              builder: (context, show, child) {
                debugPrint('Printing warning');
                if (show == 2) {
                  return const SizedBox();
                } else {
                  return NoInternetConnectionWarning(
                    isConnected: show==1,
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
            body: StreamBuilder<bool>(
              stream: _loadingController.stream,
              initialData: false,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                return Stack(children: [
                  child??const SizedBox(),
                  if (snapshot.data! == true)
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                        child: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                      ),
                    ),
                ]);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I am not able to use column in this.

Comment: You can create a widget and assign bottomNavigationBar in Scaffold in every screen.